# unexpected result of eval parse

Tags: r, parsing, loops, eval

I have a set of identically dimensioned tables for 322 areas. I need to sum these tables to 29 higher level areas and where each higher level area has varying numbers of the lower level area.

I am proposing to compute the sum in a loop, so the first task is to determine the number of lower level areas to be summed (each of which have character identifiers).

So for example the first list of lower level areas is a list of four:

```
lad_list_black
[1] "00CW" "00CU" "00CS" "00CR"
```

The higher area lists are differentiated by the last term -- in this case "black". The next is "bucks" (ie lad_list_bucks), etc.

I was proposing to use a loop which counted the number of lower level areas in its first step -- something like

```
nam <- c("black","bucks")

lad_list_black <- c("00CW","00CU","00CS","00CR")

for(i in 1:1){
eval(parse(text=length(paste("lad_list_",nam[i],sep=""))))}
```

but when I tested it outside the loop, the result was:

```
eval(parse(text=length(paste("lad_list_",nam[1],sep=""))))
[1] 1
```

which is not correct, since:

```
length(lad_list_black)
[1] 4
```

Comment: Try this `length(eval(parse(text=paste("lad_list_",nam[1],sep=""))))` #[1] 4

Comment: Or even just `text<-length(get(paste0('lad_list',nam[i])))`.

Comment: alexis_laz: perfect -- thank you so much